# How do I do VFX using a tripod?

Tags: animation, video, tracking

I'm fairly new to VFX and I've been trying to do a shot where the camera stays completely still on a tripod.
It is a video, not a single image, but the camera itself doesn't move.
How would I go about adding an animated 3D model to the footage from start to finish?
Thanks.

Comment: It's not necessary to track a still shot, it can be as simple as making some measurements, creating some placeholder geometry, and matching it up in the camera, but it depends on the level of quality you want and what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't quite understand what making measurements and creating placeholder geometry means. Could you suggest any Youtube tutorials on the subject?

Comment: Probably would be helpful to share your real static frame and some illustration what motion your 3D object should make. In general LOLock is right - to integrate 3D model into static footage you have to replicate parameters of real camera including location, rotation to blender's camera. fSpy app is straight forward solution if your footage contains parallels lines (like a building). Your source footage can help us to understand what "cards" you have in your hands to give you a helpful recommendation :)

Answer (score 1):

Motion tracking is for tracking a motion, either of the camera relative to its environment or of an object relative to the camera.

Aka Camera tracking or Object tracking:

[image: camera tracking]
[image: object tracking]

If your camera is static on a tripod, then you have no camera motion to track.
Since you wandered about motion tracking, I reckon your end goal is to reproduce your camera's position and orientation relative to the scene, in which case what you should look up for is called "camera matching" or "perspective matching".

One of the most rudimentary ways to do it is to either know your camera's specifics (resolution, focal, sensor size), copy them in your software, then try to align obvious basic shapes (I.E a plane on a tiled floor) in your 3D scene by moving the camera around with your movie in the background until it matches.
If you don't know the specs of the camera, you could try to calculate them manually, but it gets complicated.

In any case, some softwares can do it, or at least help you do it.

The infamous [fSpy](https://fspy.io/) software allows you to do exactly that. Give it a frame, draw perspective lines, and it can export a camera in a scene ready for Blender.